# error: cannot find symbol, symbol class With - Play framework java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use play framework's Composing actions using Java. I am getting a compilation error.

```
error: Cannot find symbol
@With(Menus.class)
 ^
```

Can any one tell me what is the error?

Comment: Are you importing ```play.mvc.*``` ?

Comment: Yeah. I fould the error. I forgot the import statement for @With.

    import play.mvc.With;